# How to update ebay product price using trading api in core php without using wordpress/plugin

Tags: php

I try to call XML API file in my php page like below

```
$requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$requestXmlBody = '<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
$requestXmlBody =   '<RequesterCredentials>';
$requestXmlBody =     '<eBayAuthToken>$userToken</eBayAuthToken>';
$requestXmlBody =   '</RequesterCredentials>';
$requestXmlBody =   '<Version>$version</Version>';
$requestXmlBody =   '<SKU>$sku</SKU>';
$requestXmlBody =   '<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>';
$requestXmlBody =   '<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>';
$requestXmlBody =   '<InventoryStatus>';
$requestXmlBody =     '<ItemID>$eid</ItemID>';
$requestXmlBody =     '<StartPrice>$price1</StartPrice>';
$requestXmlBody =   '</InventoryStatus>';
$requestXmlBody = '</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>';
//Create a new eBay session with all details pulled in from included keys.php
$session = new eBaySession($userToken, $devID, $appID, $certID, $serverUrl, $compatabilityLevel, $siteID, $verb);
```

But I don't know which value to set in `$verb` variable to use the `ReviseInventoryStatusRequest` function.

Comment: Please format your code to make it easier to read

Answer (score 0):

After lot's of try I achieve my target...
below solution help you

```
require_once 'ReviseInventoryStatusRequestType.php';
        $reviseinventorystatusrequest = new ReviseInventoryStatusRequestType();
        $inventorystatus = new InventoryStatusType();
        $reviseinventorystatusrequest->addInventoryStatus($inventorystatus);
        $inventorystatus->setItemID("Your item id");
        //$inventorystatus->setQuantity("qty");
        $inventorystatus->setSKU("Your SKU");
        $amount = new AmountType();
        $inventorystatus->setStartPrice($price1);
        $amount->setTypeValue($price1);
        $reviseinventorystatusrequest->setWarningLevel("High");
        $reviseinventorystatusrequest->setVersion("Version");
        $reviseinventorystatusrequest->setMessageID("test");
        $reviseinventorystatusrequest->setErrorLanguage("en_US");

         $response = $proxy->ReviseInventoryStatus($reviseinventorystatusrequest);
```